# How to call this Bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curve

With Anchor point inside and with two Handle lines that with different lengths and different angles (i.e. 90 degree between two Handle line). And Handle lines of two Anchors does not cross between each other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there's a name for this particular class of Bezier curves, but I can't say that with any confidence. Still ... it doesn't seem like a notion that's likely to occur often enough to deserve a name. In 35 years of messing with computer graphics, I've never heard one.